# Excel download using Angular and Spring Boot produces corrupt xls file

Tags: excel, angular, spring-boot, download, filesaver.js

Iam trying to write a xls download for my Spring boot application. In order to generate the file Iam using POI. If I download the file directly from my Controller without passing it to the front-end like so:

```
    //Wrote this one just for testing if the file is already corrupt here. 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dev\\directDownload.xls");
    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

It works just fine and the file looks like this:

xls when downloaded from the backend without passing it to angular:

[image]

However thats not my goal. I intend to pass the Outputstream to my angular component. The Component calls a function from a service class. This class gets the response from the controller and passes it back to my component. In the UI the downloading dialog opens. The problem is, that the downloaded file looks like this (doesnt matter if its opened via excel or open office):

Currupt xls:

[image]

My Java Controller:

```
   @CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders = "Content-Disposition")
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/file", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8")
public void getReportFile(@RequestParam(name = "projectNumber") final String projectNumber,
                          @RequestParam(name = "month") final int month, @RequestParam(name = "year") final int year,
                          @RequestParam(name = "employee") final int employee,
                          @RequestParam(name = "tsKey") final String tsKey,
                          final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
    String excelFileName = "test.xls";
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            excelFileName);
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    //Here I create the workbook that I want to download
    ProjectMonthReport report = reportService.getReport(projectNumber, month, year);
    //ExcelService builts the workbook using POI
    Workbook workbook = excelService.exportExcel(report, employee, tsKey);


    //The response is stored in an outputstream
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    byte[] byteArray = ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).getBytes();
    out.write(byteArray);
    out.flush();
    out.close();


    //Wrote this one just for testing if the file is already corrupt here. --> It's fine.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dev\\directDownload.xls");
    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

The Java Service method that builds the file using POI:

```
     public Workbook exportExcel(final ProjectMonthReport report, final int employee, final String tsKey) throws IOException,
        InvalidFormatException {
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

    // Create a Sheet
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee");

    // Create a Font for styling header cells
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

    // Create a CellStyle with the font
    CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

    Row headeRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell dateHeader = headeRow.createCell(0);
    dateHeader.setCellValue("Datum");
    Cell startHeader = headeRow.createCell(1);
    startHeader.setCellValue("Beginn");
    Cell endHeader = headeRow.createCell(2);
    endHeader.setCellValue("Ende");
    Cell activityHeader = headeRow.createCell(3);
    activityHeader.setCellValue("Tätigkeitsbereit");
    Cell cardHeader = headeRow.createCell(4);
    cardHeader.setCellValue("Kartennummer");

    List<WorkDescriptionDetail> details = report.getEmployees().get(employee).getKeyDetailMap().get(Integer.valueOf(tsKey)).getDetailList();

    int counter = 1;
    for (WorkDescriptionDetail detail : details) {

        List <String> stringList= detail.toStringList();

        Row row = sheet.createRow(counter);
        Cell cellDate = row.createCell(0);
        cellDate.setCellValue(stringList.get(0));

        Cell cellStart = row.createCell(1);
        cellStart.setCellValue(stringList.get(1));

        Cell cellEnd = row.createCell(2);
        cellEnd.setCellValue(stringList.get(2));

        Cell cellActivity = row.createCell(3);
        cellActivity.setCellValue(stringList.get(3));
        counter ++;
    }

    return workbook;
}
```

My angular component:

```
  saveFile(employee: string, tsKey:string) {
   this.subscription = this.reportService.saveXlsFile(this.projectNumber, this.year, this.month, employee, tsKey)
        .subscribe(response=> {
            console.log(response);
                let mediatype = 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8';

                const data  = new Blob(["\ufeff",response.arrayBuffer()], {type: mediatype});
                console.log(data);
                saveAs(data, 'test.xls');

            },
            error => console.log("error downloading the file"));

}
```

The Ts Service Function that is called:

```
    saveXlsFile(projectNumber:string, year:string, month:string, empId: string, tsKey:string) {
    let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('projectNumber', projectNumber);
    console.log(projectNumber);
    params.set('month', month);
    console.log(month);
    params.set( 'year', year);
    console.log(year);
    params.set('employee', empId);
    console.log(empId);
    params.set('tsKey', tsKey);
    console.log(tsKey);

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/file", { search: params } );
}
```

I tried to retrieve the response via Postman and directly download the file. When I do that the file can't be opened by excel (Excel just crashed), however I can open the file in the OpenOffice version and it works fine. Its also not corrupted.

I've been searching the web for the last couple of days and I think it may be an enconding problem caused in the frontend. But maybe it is also SpringBoot thats playing me here. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh and what I forgot to add: When opening the corrupted xls I get the following alert from excel: file format doesn't match file extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I found the solution to this problem yesterday myself. Adding the following in the angular service:

```
   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/file", { search: params, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
        (res) => {
            return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        });
```

After that you'll need to modify the component like so:

```
   saveFile(employee: string, tsKey:string) {
   this.subscription = this.reportService.saveXlsFile(this.projectNumber, this.year, this.month, employee, tsKey)
        .subscribe(response=> {
            console.log(response);
                let mediatype = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                saveAs(response, 'test.xlsx');
            },
            error => console.log("error downloading the file"));
}
```

So the Problem was that I was not getting a blob Object in my response....